# pywinauto.keyboard.KeySequenceError: `)` should be preceeded by `(`

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events, pywinauto

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lppio/PycharmProjects/WorkTexter/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    typeNumber.type_keys(row[2])  # inputs number
  File "C:\Users\lppio\PycharmProjects\WorkTexter\venv\Chromium_Filler_Test\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 964, in type_keys
    keyboard.send_keys(
  File "C:\Users\lppio\PycharmProjects\WorkTexter\venv\Chromium_Filler_Test\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\keyboard.py", line 708, in send_keys
    keys = parse_keys(
  File "C:\Users\lppio\PycharmProjects\WorkTexter\venv\Chromium_Filler_Test\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\keyboard.py", line 643, in parse_keys
    raise KeySequenceError('`)` should be preceeded by `(`')
pywinauto.keyboard.KeySequenceError: `)` should be preceeded by `(`
```

I'm getting the error above from this specific line of code and i'm not sure how to solve it:

```
    typeNumber = appWin[work].child_window(title="Type name, number or email", control_type="Edit")
        typeNumber.type_keys(row[2])
```

The script was working fine moments ago but now when i try to restart it i get that. I specifically think the problem is caused by the `typeNumber.type_keys(row[2])` part of the code; but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to unescape brackets as they mean some key code like `{ENTER}` or `(ENTER)` for example. The solution should look like:

```
typeNumber.type_keys(row[2].replace(')', '{)}').replace('(', '{(}'))
```

If `row[2]` may contain `{` or `}`, just replace it by `({)` or `(})`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a ')' and a '}' in the string you couldn't solve that with replace, instead loop over each character and fix by wrapping with brackets:

```
password = 'ss{)747&FH%4)}'
clean_pass = ''
for c in password:
    if c in ['(', ')', '{', '}', '%']:
        clean_pass += ('{' + c + '}')
    else:
        clean_pass += c
print(clean_pass)
```